# Trying to click on the checkbox using selenium webdriver in python but getting -- MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to click on the checkbox on this website https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals . For that I use ActionChains library. At first I tried by simply getting the input tag of the checkbox by xpath or css seletor and using click() to click on it but then i got element not interactable error so I triedclick ActionChains to move over to the element and then clicking it but then i getting the following error -  MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: move target out of bounds

````
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

actions =ActionChains(browser)
WebDriverWait(browser,5)
.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(('xpath','//input[@id="autocompleteKeywordInput"]')))
termbox = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#disclaimerIdCheckbox')
actions.move_to_element(termbox).click(termbox).perform()

inputField = browser.find_element('xpath','//input[@id="autocompleteKeywordInput"]')
typeInput = actions.move_to_element(inputField).click(inputField).send_keys('100-09-4').perform()

WebDriverWait(browser,5)
get_url = browser.current_url
print("The current url is:"+str(get_url))```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Cppt.png
````

Answer (score 0):

In case all you are looking for here is to click the checkbox, the only thing you need to fix is the locator. It is not the `input` but `label` element who should be clicked.
The below code works

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

s = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=s)

url = 'https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals'

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'disclaimerIdCheckboxLabel'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals')
  # WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "label[for='disclaimerIdCheckbox']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://echa.europa.eu/information-on-chemicals')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[@for='disclaimerIdCheckbox']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: europa]